# Python3.x: If/Else trouble

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.x

I'm having some trouble with my if/else statements. Here's my code, the question is described in a multi-line comment in the code itself:

```
def cube(*number):
    return number**3
def by_three(number):
    if number/3==0: #Checks if number is divisible by 3.
        cube_of=cube(number) #Cubes number.
        print(cube_of) #Prints cube of number.
        return False
    else:
        print("Your number isn't divisible by three. Try again.") #Comment is below
        """
        Tells if number is not divisible by three. If I give 9 as the argument, 
        this block is executed. Why so?
        """
        return True
while True:
    by_three(int(input("Give me any number divisible by three: ")))
```

The question is in the code. Please use simple terms in your answers as I am only a beginner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use modulo operator not division operator.

```
if number % 3 == 0:
```

Try

```
print(9 % 3)
print(9 / 3)
```

You will get

```
0
3.0
```

Modulo operator returns the remainder of the division and the division operator returns the quotient of the division.

Comment: »Why so«?  Because `9 / 3` = `3` ≠ `0`  ;-)

Comment: @Alfe He wants to check the divisibility.

Comment: I know.  I just boiled the answer down to a line not worth an answer section here.  I'm pretty sure that would have been hint enough ;-)

Comment: If people just knew that they could use `print` as a poor mans debugger to check their values we could get rid of a lot of pretty simple questions here.